# php regular expression extract strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, multiple-matches

i have test it for hours using php preg_match_all to extract data, but with no luck.

original data:

```
"media":{"content":[{"url":"zz.abc.com/-5vPApXfHhjw/VWsfGkM05jI/AAAAAAAAABI/qr6IodAAnJg/heyzo_hd_0870_full-cut.gif","height":288,"width":512,"type":"image/gif"},{"url":"zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m19","height":360,"width":640,"type":"video/mpeg4"},{"url":"zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m28","height":720,"width":1280,"type":"video/mpeg4"},{"url":"zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m39","height":1080,"width":1920,"type":"video/mpeg4"}],"description":"","
```

i want to extract:
zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m19

zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m28

zz.abc.com/lZY0lTdOkOLn-uwa_Qkgt_ywfmnxV1B9qfzAur_KQw=m39

i use:

```
preg_match_all("/(?<!\[\{\"url\":\")(zz\.abc\.com)(.*?[a-zA-Z]\d\d)(?=\",\"height\")/", $html, $matches);

if ($matches[0][1]!=""){
echo $matches[0][1];
}
if ($matches[0][2]!=""){
echo $matches[0][2];
}
if ($matches[0][3]!=""){
echo $matches[0][3];
}
```

please advise how to output my data and much appreciated.

Comment: Why not to use `json_decode`?

Comment: don't complex that much simply decode it and get the value.`json_decode`

Comment: i don't familiar with json_decode, can you give me an example

Comment: is your json data is full and correct what you pasted here?

Comment: no, just a part which i want to extract

Comment: Please put fill data.